# bootstrap modal within nav tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've placed a button to activate a 'twitter bootstrap modal' on the 3rd tab within a 'navtab'. When the modal button is clicked there is a short delay then the 1st tab of the navtab is set to active. At no point is the modal visible.

My assumption is that the modal defaults to the first tab and that when the tab changes from tab 3 to tab 1 an event is fired that causes the modal to close.

Which leads me to the question: how can I set the modal to activate on tab n rather than tab 1?

Am I completely wrong about what is happening here? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="tester">Detailed</button>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" id="mymod" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '#tester', function(){
        $("#mymod").modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It should be `...example-modal-sm" id="mymod" role="dial...`.

Comment: I've edited the OP to reflect the typo. Thank you for spotting that creimers. Although the behavior I describe has not changed. Which is curious..

Comment: What if you spared the javascript and tried these button attributes: `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymod"`?

Comment: No change. I've literally copy and pasted every example from the bootstrap webpage and get the exact same behavior. Clicking the modal button changes the active tab and does nothing else.

Comment: How do you feel about a litte jsfiddle?

Comment: I should have included a jsfiddle link to begin with.. Although I think I solved my problem. I added `bootstrap-modal.js` to my static assets and now things seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I didn't have the proper javascript library loaded for bootstrap.

Adding `bootstrap-modal.js` to my static assets solved my problem.